# Null values after mapping Data to an Object

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am trying to map multiple Database entries to an Object, so I can filter it.

```
async autocomplete(interaction) {
        const focusedValue = interaction.options.getFocused();
        let choices = await items.findAll({
            attributes: ['itemID', 'desc_de'] });
        const jsondata = JSON.stringify(choices);
        const json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
        const itemObj = json.map(function(item) {
            return {
                itemID: item.itemID,
                item_desc: item.desc_de,
            };
        });
        const filtered = itemObj.filter(choice => choice.item_desc.toLowerCase().includes(focusedValue.toLowerCase()));
        await interaction.respond(
            filtered.map(choice => ({name: choice.item_desc, value: choice.itemID})),
        );
```

The issue I am having is, apparently choice.item_desc is NULL somehow, I am unsure, what I am doing wrong here.
The error is
`TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'toLowerCase')`

Before I had an object, which was only holding the itemID and with that it was working fine.

Comment: `item.desc_de` may be `null`, to which you cannot apply `.toLowerCase()`. Try `(choice.item_desc || "").toLowerCase()`, which replaces `null` with an empty string.

Comment: Curious why the OP stringify's then parses the find results. The problem can be debugged by logging focussedValue and logging itemObjs look for nulls.

Answer (score -1):

```js
let choices = await items.findAll({
            attributes: ['itemID', 'desc_de'] });
        const jsondata = JSON.stringify(choices);
        const json = JSON.parse(jsondata);
        const itemObj = json.map(function(item) {
            return {
                itemID: item.itemID,
                item_desc: item.desc_de,
            };
        });
```

The above code will run successfully without throwing an error even if "choices" is an empty array.

That said, Your query should be the issue, it seems you're trying to get all items that have 'itemID' and 'desc_de' but also seems like you're trying to query for choices that have 'itemID' and 'desc_de' in their attributes array.